# Working Experiences Sections in application systems of doctoral programs?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application

I am applying to doctoral programs and I am not sure if it is necessary to fill out the sections for working experiences.

The problem is that I have been always a full-time student up to now and, though my working experiences are many,
all of them are part-time and intermittent.
A job for two to three months,
no job,
another job for two to three months,
no job,
and so on.
Moreover,
it is very difficult for me to identify and list all the work places that I had been at their service.

Then what is the best strategy for me to tackle the sections of working experiences? Should I leave it blank or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write down everything you have done. Here in Germany you usually get an employer's reference even if you've just worked there for a short time. Hence you would know where and when you've worked. Also at least at university it is known that studies are a full time job so nobody expect that you've worked throughout your studies.

If you can't recall where you've worked that's a different problem. Try your best and if you come up with a decent amount/majority that should be good enough. Just don't underestimate the experience gained just by some work aside from your studies.

So **don't leave it blank** just try to fill it as good as possible.

Comment: Thanks. How about the work places I cannot get whose contact information now? Should I still list them out?